# Daughter won't take formula

Tags: breastfeeding, formula

We need a way to introduce formula to our daughter quick. The backup milk supply we have is no longer good due to a milk allergy so is there any quick ways to introduce formula?

Comment: Have you contacted your pediatrician?

Comment: Did you recently discover that your daughter has a milk allergy?  How did you learn of the allergy?

Comment: @jrennie blood in the diaper when my wife ate dairy products

Comment: Go to the doctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your wife is the one trying to give the formula, your daughter might refuse it because she can smell her mother's milk.  You might have to be the one to give the formula and your wife might have to leave the room.

Otherwise, dropper or a small (plastic) shotglass (It's how I gave my son expressed milk when we were having latching issues) should do until she's gotten used to the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I called the pediatrician right after posting so I am posting what we did as an answer. The Dr suggested that we try a dropper or syringe of the formula at a time. It is slow but seems to have worked. I am still leaving this open for alternative answers in case others wander across this question.